# How to access Resources in main and test files

Tags: java, resources

How to access resources(image/file) from main and test classes.
If I directly give file name where will the resources be looked first for main classes and test classes.

My requirement:
I need give a file in control folder as input to execute the jar file. And control file has file names(to access file in certificates folder) which I should access in my program.

How to give the file names in above scenarios.

Project structure is as follows
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1ekZ.png)

Comment: They should be in your CLASSPATH; access them as streams, not files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a image:

```
String path = "nameOfProject/resources/whateverfolder/imagename.png";
ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path));
```

It is donot matter which class you are in, if you pass whole path rather than file name.

To access a file:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
```